# Performance of RANK function without using analytic functions in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate rank for each partition in my test table but I am wondering what's the efficient way to implement a rank function in mysql?

Is it using variables or correlated sub-queries and which one is efficient if the data volume is large?

```
SQL Code :-



CREATE TABLE Test1(A int,B int, C int);


   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(1,11,20);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(1,11,21);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(1,11,22);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(1,12,23);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(1,12,24);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(1,12,25);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(2,13,26);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(2,13,27);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(2,13,28);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(2,14,29);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(2,14,30);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(2,14,31);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(3,15,32);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(3,15,33);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(3,14,34);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(3,14,35);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(3,14,36);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(4,15,36);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(4,15,37);

   INSERT INTO Test1 VALUES(4,15,38);



 Query :-

 SELECT t1.A,t1.B,t1.C,  
        ( SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM test1 t2        
           WHERE t1.C >= t2.C        
             AND t1.A = t2.A      
             AND t1.B = t2.B     
         ) AS rn 
   FROM test1 t1; 




  Output:-

+------+------+------+------+
| A    | B    | C    | rn   |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |   11 |   20 |    1 |
|    1 |   11 |   21 |    2 |
|    1 |   11 |   22 |    3 |
|    1 |   12 |   23 |    1 |
|    1 |   12 |   24 |    2 |
|    1 |   12 |   25 |    3 |
|    2 |   13 |   26 |    1 |
|    2 |   13 |   27 |    2 |
|    2 |   13 |   28 |    3 |
|    2 |   14 |   29 |    1 |
|    2 |   14 |   30 |    2 |
|    2 |   14 |   31 |    3 |
|    3 |   15 |   32 |    1 |
|    3 |   15 |   33 |    2 |
|    3 |   14 |   34 |    1 |
|    3 |   14 |   35 |    2 |
|    3 |   14 |   36 |    3 |
|    4 |   15 |   36 |    1 |
|    4 |   15 |   37 |    2 |
|    4 |   15 |   38 |    3 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to do it with join. In fact, even though I mostly use SQL Server, I will sometimes forego using the `rank()` function and construct it myself to ensure that I firmly understand the data.

Here's an example:

```
select t1.*, COUNT(t2.A) as m -- could count over any thing from t2, doesn't have to be A
    from Test1 t1
    left join Test1 t2
        on t2.A = t1.A
        and t2.B = t1.B
        and t2.C <= t1.C
    group by  t1.A
            , t1.B
            , t1.C
    order by  t1.A
            , t1.B
            , t1.C
```

This will do the same thing as ranking, and you can change your join conditions to rank in several different ways.

Remove the group by and use `select *` to see more detail of how this works.

Comment: Can you explain the time complexity?

Comment: @Teja No, I really don't know enough about what SQL optimizers do to give you any sort of reasonable time complexity. My explanation follows the idea that since SQL is a set-based language, it thrives on set-based operations. However, you might still be able to pull out some data. Find several data sets and run the join way vs. the sub-query way to see how they perform.